# How to use db.collection.findOne function along with pretty in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Why does `pretty()` is not supported for `findOne()` in **mongoDB**.

`db.collection.find().pretty()` is acceptable but `db.collection.findOne().pretty()` is not acceptable.  Any reason?.  Someone would say that findOne() already prints in a pretty format so need of calling pretty() again but the point is why it is not supported in mongoDB as it is just a function which prints/displays the result in pretty format. Please let me know why it is not allowed in mongoDB.

Edit:
I just observed that if the collection is empty , `db.collection.find()` will return nothing where as `db.collection.findOne()` will return **null**.   Why is it so ?

Comment: `find()` returns a cursor, `findOne()` returns a document.  What were you expecting?

Comment: `findOne` has pretty built into it. `findOne` returns a document, and if none exists or matches the query filter, returns a `null`. These are basic things you can read in a manual.

Comment: I need to invoke findOne without pretty. what's the option

Comment: Pretty is just a display format.  What's the purpose here?  If you are trying to scrape the data from console output, there is probably a better way to do whatever it is.